# CSS: Debugging div width on android 2.3.x

Tags: android, html, css, debugging

I'm trying in vain to discover why a div (".about-text-column") on the page [here](http://ec2-52-37-250-134.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com/category/about/) is wider than 60% on an Android 2.3.7 mobile device (it's 60% on all other devices with < 1000px width I have nearby).

I know that for Android > 4, one can use [remote debugging](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/debug/remote-debugging/remote-debugging?hl=en), but I'm at a loss regarding how to proceed with this Android. Does anyone know a good way to debug this kind of display error on these ancient devices? I'd be very grateful for any advice others can offer on this question!